# Slow printing in Python but without truncating words

Tags: python

I am writing a text adventure for some fun in Python and found a cool function that prints the text to the terminal slowly:

```
def print_slow(str):
for letter in str:
    sys.stdout.write(letter)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

However, as it is writing it letter by letter if the word doesn't finish before the end of the line it will truncate it i.e:

```
bla bla bla bla rea
ding.
```

Whereas I rather it do:

```
bla bla bla bla
reading
```

Any easy way of doing this?

FULL CODE: Please ignore the bad story, this was just a proof of concept that I could get it to work! :)

```
from __future__ import print_function
import textwrap
import sys,time,random
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *


def print_slow(str):
    for letter in str:
        sys.stdout.write(letter)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.1)


def displayIntro():
    pygame.mixer.init()
    pygame.mixer.music.load('storm.wav')
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    print('')
    print('')

    for line in textwrap.wrap(a,20):
        print_slow('The year is 2054, you have just arrived home from four years of travelling ')
        print()
    print_slow('The year is 2054, you have just arrived home from four years of travelling ')
    print_slow('Europe, studying the virus that has killed all the grass in the mainland. ')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('\n')
    pygame.mixer.music.load('metaldoor.wav')
    pygame.mixer.music.play(0)
    print_slow('As you open the gates of your estate, you hear a familar voice coming from ')
    print_slow('the house. ')
    time.sleep(1)

def gateDecision():
    decision = ''
    print('\n') 
    print_slow('As you walk down the drive, the voice suddenly turns into a scream. ')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('\n')
    print_slow('You start running, getting to the door which is locked. ')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('\n')
    print_slow('You reach into your pocket to get the key, but it is locked from the inside. ')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('\n')

    while decision != 'a' and decision != 'b':
    print_slow('Do you: ')
    print('\n')
        print_slow('(a) Climb in through the open window, or (b) Go around and try the back door?')
    decision = raw_input()

    if decision == "a":
        time.sleep(1)
        print('')
        print_slow('As you open the window, you feel the shotgun against your forehead and the ')
        pygame.mixer.music.load('shotgun.wav')
        pygame.mixer.music.play(0)
        print_slow('cool breeze of air that rushes through your skull as you drop to the ')
    print_slow('ground dead. ')
    print('\n')
    print_slow('THE END... ')
    print('\n')
    print('\n')
    else:
        time.sleep(1)
        print_slow('You get to the back door to find it ajar, you slowly step in... ')
print('-------------------------------------------------------------')        
print('\n')
print('\n')
print('\n')
print('\n')
print('\n')
print('\n')
print('\n')
print(' #    # # #####  #    #  ####  ')
print(' #    # # #    # #    # #      ')
print(' #    # # #    # #    #  ####  ')
print(' #    # # #####  #    #      # ')
print('  #  #  # #   #  #    # #    # ')
print('   ##   # #    #  ####   ####  ')

displayIntro()
gateDecision()
```

Comment: Why the downvote? -- To the OP: It is *not easy* to do that, but it is possible, providing that the console width is fixed.

Comment: Not sure why it was downvoted, maybe people don't like programming for fun or text adventures :).... my bad if it is not what StackOverflow is for.
I could fix the width of the program and make sure that IDLE is the same width so I can manually make sure it doesn't go over

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3? It's easier in Python 3, since you have [`shutil.get_terminal_size()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.get_terminal_size). Python 2 needs [`backports.shutil_get_terminal_size`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/backports.shutil_get_terminal_size).

Comment: Python 2, I think BoarGules has a solution. Going to try it out :)... thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `textwrap` to split your text into lines. Call `print_slow()` to output each line and after it print a newline.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import textwrap
for line in textwrap.wrap(a,20):
    print_slow(line)
    print()
```

Comment: Hey, thank you ever so much. I am just testing it now. What is the 'a' for in the textwrap code? I ask as it is saying I haven't defined it.

Comment: You showed your `print_slow()` function but not the code that called it. I have to pass it something to print. That something is in `a`. `a = "bla bla bla bla reading."`.

Comment: Ahhh, I see. It is in a function that I wrote which is called lower in in the script. Let me quickly add all of my script so far to my original question, will take me 30 secs! Thank you!

Comment: Would it help if I expressed it `for line in textwrap.wrap(my_adventure_game_text_that_I_want_printed_slowly,20):`